# AutoLogin in Answer File

Tags: windows-7, deployment

I am trying to get passed the creation of the account with an answer file when loading an image  on another machine.

I have:

```
<component name="Microsoft-Windows-Shell-Setup" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <AutoLogon>
                <Password>
                    <Value>xxx</Value>
                    <PlainText>false</PlainText>
                </Password>
                <Enabled>true</Enabled>
                <LogonCount>5</LogonCount>
                <Username>AdminUser</Username>
            </AutoLogon>
```

`AdminUser` is the admin account I created when I did the configuration of the reference machine. I would like the setup to us this account instead of having to create a new one during the setup process.

Is this possible? What am I missing? What are the requirements for autologin and having the answer file tell the setup to not ask for a user name a password during installation?

Answer (score 1):

When attempting to configure an autologin in a windows setup, you have to use the built in admin account. MDT 2012 can build an answer file for you that will do this.

The easiest thing to do is just use the MDT default of simply turning the Admin account back on. But if you're really adamant about creating a separate account, try this...

In the windows system image manager (WISM),

First create the account in the 4 specialize pass.

Most people do this in the Run Synchronous Command Section. This is where most people will simply turn the Administrator account back on, but if you want to create an account via the answer file use the following syntax

```
net user /add useraccountname mypassword
```

and

```
net localgroup administrators useraccountname /add
```

[image]
Create the account

[image]
Set The Password

[image]

Then you must set this account as the autologon account in the 7 OOBE pass.

If you're just using WISM by itself, and not using MDT, look into using it in combination with just WISM.

The link below has some good videos on the tool.

http://www.deploymentresearch.com/Videos/MDT2010LiteTouchUnleashedVideos.aspx